# Coverting pd.DataFrame: Lists to strings

Tags: python, list, pandas, type-conversion, newline

I currently have csv file that is structured as follows:

```
url,text
http://example1.com,"['Animal' 'Giraffe' 'Drawing' 'Font'
 'Graphics' 'Map' 'Paper'
 'Text' 'Writing']"
http://example2.com,"['Table' 'Chair' 'Long hair'
  'Selfie' 'Smile']"
...
```

Import:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
```

Problem is: When importing the csv, the pandas DF imports \n for new lines, too:

```
df['text'][0]
"['Animal' 'Giraffe' 'Drawing' 'Font'\n 'Graphics' 'Map' 'Paper'\n 'Text' 'Writing']"

df['text'][1]
"['Table' 'Chair' 'Long hair'\n 'Selfie' 'Smile'"
```

For example, this is what I need in the end:

```
animal, giraffe, drawing, font, graphics, individual sport, laptop, map, paper, text, writing
```

I.e. a script that removes the newlines or imports correctly, and then converts the list into a clean string. This didn't work:

```
df['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
df['text']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `convertor` keyword in `read_csv` function by first stripping the `text` column and then splitting with whitespace:

```
In [25]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'text': lambda x: x.strip('[]').split()})

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
                   url                                               text
0  http://example1.com  ['Animal', 'Giraffe', 'Drawing', 'Font', 'Grap...
1  http://example2.com  ['Table', 'Chair', 'Long, hair', 'Selfie', 'Sm...
```

Note that if you had `,` in between your array items you could also use `ast.literal_eval()` directly on your column.(after removing the `\n` though!).

Comment: Solves the import, correct. Would it make sense to include the "unlisting" i.e. flattening of the list here, too? Or rather independent, like below?

Comment: @Christopher This is definitely more Pythonic  because it doesn't apply the manipulating functions after once loading it into the memory (creating the column, calling the underlying functions etc.).

Comment: Okay, thank you. And how about the unlisting, as shown above?

Comment: @Christopher You mean as a concatenated string?

Comment: Yes, that was part of the problem that above script solved for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'inefficiency' of the other approach you mention? Time comparison?

Comment: @Christopher In that case you can simply use `lambda x: x.strip('[]').replace('\n', '', 1).replace(' ', ',')` as the converter function.

Comment: @Christopher Time and memory both. Especially when the size of the file is notably huge.

Comment: Last one: The solution you mention creates a list. I need a string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164461/discussion-between-christopher-and-kasramvd).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['new'] = df['text'].str.strip("[]'").str.split("'\s+'").str.join(', ')
print (df)

                   url                                               text  \
0  http://example1.com  ['Animal' 'Giraffe' 'Drawing' 'Font'\n 'Graphi...   
1  http://example2.com  ['Table' 'Chair' 'Long hair'\n  'Selfie' 'Smile']   

                                                 new  
0  Animal, Giraffe, Drawing, Font, Graphics, Map,...  
1             Table, Chair, Long hair, Selfie, Smile
```

If you want column of `list`s:

```
df['new'] = df['text'].str.strip("[]'").str.split("'\s+'")
print (df)

                   url                                               text  \
0  http://example1.com  ['Animal' 'Giraffe' 'Drawing' 'Font'\n 'Graphi...   
1  http://example2.com  ['Table' 'Chair' 'Long hair'\n  'Selfie' 'Smile']   

                                                 new  
0  [Animal, Giraffe, Drawing, Font, Graphics, Map...  
1           [Table, Chair, Long hair, Selfie, Smile]
```

Comment: Can you quickly comment, what it does? Never used ast

Comment: Looking good! I will mark as solved after waiting for some potential alternatives, if that's okay? Is there a difference between `.replace('\\n','', regex=True)` and `.replace('\n','', regex=True)` ?

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: It wasn't me, checked that.

Comment: Alongside the inefficiency of your approach, I think the downvote is because you destroyed the original type of the `text` column and created a concatenated string of it.

Comment: I think the latter is what I desired, not?

Comment: If want `list`s, need last solution, if need `string`s use first.

Comment: @jezrael a good solution seemed: `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'Labels': lambda x: ', '.join(re.findall(r'\w+', x))})`. I compared speeds and the other solution seemed a bit faster. Nevertheless, I made sure to upvote your contributions. Unfortunately, I can't mark both solutions as solved.